# How to write a script that will put a datestamp in a cell when a checkbox is checked, and remove when removed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script in Google Sheets that will allow me to have a datestamp entered in a cell when a checkbox is checked in the row that cell is in. I have gotten the first part done thanks to web searches, but the second part of the task I am having issues with.

Once the checkbox has been checked the datestamp does indeed go in the cell, but when I uncheck the checkbox it just updates the date in the cell, but does not remove it.

I am sure I am just missing something easy, but as I do not normally code, and only have a somewhat firm grasp on formulas even, this is a bit out of my ability to troubleshoot. If anyone could look at this and help me figure out what variables would be tied to what I am doing, and which ones I have gotten wrong (ideally with comments so I can understand what each line of code is trying to do), I would appreciate it.

Here is the script:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Writing Team Tasks" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 4); { //offset for the non-adjacent column
if( r.getValue() === "") { //checks if the cell being edited is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue("");
}
else
{
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
}
}
```

I am hoping to have a script that will enter a date stamp when a checkbox is checked, and then remove the datestamp if the checkbox becomes unchecked. Currently, I am able to do all of that, except remove the datestamp.

Comment: Your code and comments do not match `if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A` column5 is E

Comment: Does it need to be a script or can it be a formula as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Writing Team Tasks" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value =="TRUE") { 
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (sh.getName() == "Writing Team Tasks" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value =="FALSE") { 
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked like a dream and made the whole thing far less complex!

Comment: Hi, this code is no longer working. When I debug it, it says that under Local e and sh are undefined.

This is the code I am using now.

function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Writing Team Tasks" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value =="TRUE") { 
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (sh.getName() == "Writing Team Tasks" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value =="FALSE") { 
    e.range.offset(0,4).setValue('');
  }
}

Any idea why it is broken now?

Comment: You can run this code from the editor unless you supply the event object which populates the e parameter. If you wish to run it in debug mode you will need to use an intermediate function in order to create the event object artificially.  Personally I debug code like this by editing the sheet and putting toasts to see where it's going

Comment: I am trying to run it in the Apps Script editor, but when I click run it pops the error Type Error: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2.

Unfortunately I have no idea what that means so I am not able to figure out how to resolve the error.

Comment: Do you have the e in the onEdit

Comment: I have not changed the code since you first ran it.

Comment: The first line of the script says "function onEdit(e)"

Comment: Figured it out, someone had added another column and I did not notice initially. Just had to change the column reference. It is still throwing the error in the editor, but it works.

Comment: Without a script! https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494266/14915635

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a formula first if you do not have to do it as a script.

A formula is visible on the cell and not hidden from view of someone using the worksheet.

For this, a formula would look like the Date column (B) below:

| row \ col | *A* | *B* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Done** | **Date** |
| 2 | ☑ | =IF(($A2=TRUE), TODAY(), "") |
| 3 | ☐ | =IF(($A3=TRUE), TODAY(), "") |

And the output would look like this:

[image: Screenshot of table above]

Basically, it checks if the the value of the cell is TRUE and displays today's date if so.  If not, it displays a blank (empty) string

Comment: Hi,

I like this version as well. But this only inputs the datestamp when the box is checked, it does not then pull it back out if the box is unchecked. Is there a way to do that with this formula?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, if the checkbox is selected, it writes the datestamp, otherwise, it replaces it with a blank string (i.e. `""`) leaving an empty cell.  Does that not work for you?